# Content formatting for Cron job email alert

Tags: java, cron

We schedule cron jobs on a ubuntu server 10.04, the scripts that we execute contains the 
commands  maven clean package & then execute a java class.

The  email alert report after the job completion is verbose, The email is pretty lengthy detailing all the actions taken. In the email i just want few last lines, and if the job fails then the detailed error report.

One option i have is to store the result in a log file, and tail the output. But if the jobs fails i may not get the complete report.

Can i do this using some other java class or any other alternatives.

Any tips/advise is appreciated.

--
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Write a perl/shell script to process the log file and then call that script as a cron-job. Write the script in such a way that, if the job passes, it extracts the last few lines alone (may be, using the `tail` command), and if the job fails, output the entire file). I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this was what I did, when I faces a similar situation.

Comment: Its actually a "mvn clean package" command so how should i check the condition in shell script.